# Microsoft Graph Client C#: Missing DeltaToken and SkipToken

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-sdks, graphserviceclient

I'm using GraphServiceClient V5.7.0 to sync personal contacts with my desktop application and would like to use [delta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/contact-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) to get only changes since my last sync.

In [Microsoft's example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-users?tabs=csharp) it say to use SkipToken or DeltaToken in the QueryParameters (i linked user example becauese there is no example for personal contacts)

```
var result = await graphClient.Users.Delta.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Skiptoken = "oEBwdSP6uehIAxQOWq_3Ksh_TLol6KIm3stvdc6hGhZRi1hQ7Spe__dpvm3U4zReE4CYXC2zOtaKdi7KHlUtC2CbRiBIUwOxPKLa";
});
```

But QueryParameters doesn't have SkipToken parameter.
I found [this GitHub's issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1689), and they suggest to use

```
requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Add("%24skiptoken", "skiptoken");
```

But QueryParameters doesn't have even Add method.

Is there any solution to complete the request without waiting for the correction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the workaround you need to create `RequestInformation` and when you access `QueryParameters` on `RequestInformation` you should be able to call `Add` method.

When using `GetAsync((requestConfiguration)` or `ToGetRequestInformation((requestConfiguration)` the type of `requestConfiguration.QueryParameters` is `DeltaRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters` and it has no method to add custom query parameter.

```
var requestInformation = graphClient.Users.Delta.ToGetRequestInformation((requestConfiguration) =>
        {
            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Count = true;
        });
requestInformation.UrlTemplate = requestInformation.UrlTemplate.Insert(requestInformation.UrlTemplate.Length - 1, ",%24skiptoken,%24deltatoken,changeType");
requestInformation.QueryParameters.Add("%24skiptoken", "skiptoken");
requestInformation.QueryParameters.Add("changeType", "created");
requestInformation.QueryParameters.Add("%24deltatoken", "deltatoken");

var result = await graphClient.RequestAdapter.SendAsync(requestInformation, UserCollectionResponse.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue);
```

Comment: My mistake, I hadn't noticed that it used the ToGetRequestInformation method. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered exactly the same problem, and the answer by user2250152 was not helpful for me, but I managed to solve it eventually. My solution was the following:

```
string skipToken = result.OdataNextLink[(result.OdataNextLink.IndexOf("$skiptoken=") + "$skiptoken=".Length)..];

Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.RequestInformation requestInformation = graphClient
                        .Drives[driveId]
                        .Items[itemId]
                        .Children
                        .ToGetRequestInformation();

requestInformation.UrlTemplate = requestInformation.UrlTemplate[..^1] + ",%24skiptoken" + requestInformation.UrlTemplate[^1];

requestInformation.QueryParameters.Add("%24skiptoken", skipToken);

DriveItemCollectionResponse nextResult = await graphClient
                        .RequestAdapter
                        .SendAsync(requestInformation, DriveItemCollectionResponse.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue);
```